# codecvt header file replacement in linux

Tags: linux

I am ruuning the following code in window:-

```
#include <codecvt>
void main()
{
    wifstream myfile (argv[1],ios_base::in|ios_base::binary);   
    myfile.imbue(std::locale(myfile.getloc(),new std::codecvt_utf16<wchar_t, 0xffff, consume_header>));
}
```

I would like to compile the code in linux, but "codecvt" header file is not supported and gettign erro for codecvt_utf16 and consume_header, few suggest use ICU or iconv header file.But I dont know how to use them.

Please help me in replacing the code that can run in linux
Thanks & Regards
Vikas

Answer (score 6):

[`std::codecvt`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/codecvt/) is properly part of [`<locale>`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/locale/); it doesn't have its own header. A given compiler might split its implementation up, but the names of sub-pieces are implementation details.

Comment: Good! In that case you should [mark the answer accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) so your question falls off the "unanswered question" list. You should do this for your other open questions too...

Comment: Hello? Please give puetzk credit by accepting his answer. Saved me much time.

Answer (score 0):

Poco::UnicodeConvert utility is able to handle the common code conversion, and it is portable.

For example:

string toUTF8(const Poco::UTF16String & utf16String) {
    string result;

```
Poco::UnicodeConverter::convert(utf16String, result);

return result;
```

}